# newline-delimited JSON to excel file using php

Tags: php, json, mixpanel

From mixpanel API i am getting `newline-delimited JSON` as response .I need to store this information in excel file or how can i convert this json response to single valid json .How can i do with PHP. Any one please suggest

This is the response from mixpanel

```
{"event":"Login","properties":{"time":1445803474,"distinct_id":"601","$browser":"Chrome","$browser_version":46,"$city":"cityname","$current_url":"http://localhost","$initial_referrer":"$direct","$initial_referring_domain":"$direct","$lib_version":"2.7.1","$os":"Windows","$region":"Region name","$screen_height":768,"$screen_width":1366,"mp_country_code":"countrycode","mp_lib":"web","userName":"local@gmail.com"}} 
{"event":"game","properties":{"time":1445803562,"distinct_id":"602","$browser":"Chrome","$browser_version":46,"$city":"cityname","$current_url":"http://localhost","$initial_referrer":"$direct","$initial_referring_domain":"$direct","$lib_version":"2.7.1","$os":"Windows","$region":"Region name","$screen_height":768,"$screen_width":1366,"mp_country_code":"countrycode","mp_lib":"web","userName":"local1@gmail.com"}}
```

Comment: Please a provide a sample of your JSON and what you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asking for PHP... there is a PHP Client proposed in the docs: https://mixpanel.com/docs/api-documentation/data-export-api#libs-php

Comment: i am getting the response but the problem is the response string line by line JSON.I need to convert this JSON data to excel. Is it possible using PHP?